# Queue with balanced lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, queue, instance

I'm trying to write a definition for balanced lists in haskell. QueueA should be the queue with balanced lists:

```
module QueueA where 

import Queue

data QueueA a = QA [a] [a]

instance Queue (Queue a) where
    empty = QA [] []

    (|>) (QA a b) el = norm $ QA a (el : b)

    head (QA a _) = Prelude.head a

    tail (QA a b) = norm $ QA (Prelude.tail a) b

    toList queue = Queue.head queue : Queue.tail queue


norm :: [a] -> [a]
norm queue@(QA a b) = if (length a) >= (length b) then queue else QA (a ++ reverse b) []
```

based on the interface Queue

```
module Queue where

class Queue a where
     empty :: a
     (|>) :: a -> a -> a
     null :: a -> Bool
     head :: a -> a
     tail :: a -> a
     toList :: a -> [a]
```

I have no idea how to define the interface correctly, I based this around an example i found. Most errors look like this:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `QueueA a1'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration
      at C:\Users\kroll\Dropbox\WS 16.17\Moderne Funktionale Programmierung\Übung\Blatt 8\Code\Queue
```

I know that defining empty :: a is probably wrong, but empty :: Queue a doesn't work either.

Comment: Shouldn't your instance declaration be Queue (QueueA a) instead?

Answer (score 3):

I think @bheklilr's answer is more complicated than necessary. I reckon a good-enough definition of a queue class can be given in pure Haskell 98:

```
class Queue q where
    empty :: q a
    push :: a -> q a -> q a
    pop :: q a -> Maybe (a, q a)
```

No need for type families or functional dependencies, unless you need to do advanced [`mono-traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable)-like tricks.

The rest of the functions in your class can be squeezed through this toothpaste tube:

```
-- it may make sense to make this into a class method with a default implementation,
-- so that instances can give an optimised implementation where possible
null :: (Eq (q a), Queue q) => q a -> Bool
null q = q == empty

-- head and tail are unsafe! I don't recommend writing an interface like this
head :: Queue q => q a -> a
head = fst . fromJust . pop

tail :: Queue q => q a -> q a
tail = snd . fromJust . pop

(|>) :: Queue q => q a -> a -> q a
(|>) = flip push

toList :: Queue q => q a -> [a]
toList = unfoldr pop
```

Your first-in-first-out queue can be made into an instance of `Queue` straightforwardly:

```
instance Queue QueueA where
    empty = QA [] []

    push x (QA front back) = QA front (x:back)

    pop (QA [] []) = Nothing
    pop (QA [] back) =
        let (x:xs) = reverse back
        in Just (x, QA xs [])
    pop (QA (x:front) back) = Just (x, QA front back)
```

... as can a last-in-first-out queue:

```
newtype LIFO a = LIFO [a]

instance Queue LIFO where
    empty = LIFO []
    push x (LIFO xs) = LIFO (x:xs)
    pop (LIFO []) = Nothing
    pop (LIFO (x:xs)) = Just (x, LIFO xs)
```

---

If you want to include priority queues in your abstraction, it gets somewhat more complicated, because a priority queue needs to know how to choose the highest-priority element and the given interface provides no way of comparing elements. One way to patch up `Queue` would be to use the `ConstraintKinds` extension (with `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies`) to enable `q` to specify the constraint it places on its elements:

```
class Queue c q | q -> c where
    empty :: c a => q a
    push :: c a => a -> q a -> q a
    pop :: c a => q a -> Maybe (a, q a)
```

Then we can implement a priority queue using, eg, the *skew heap* from [*Playing With Priority Queues*](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/issue16.pdf)...

```
instance Queue Ord SkewHeap where  -- SkewHeap requires that its elements be an instance of Ord
    empty = Empty
    push x q = q `merge` SkewNode x Empty Empty
    pop Empty = Nothing
    pop (SkewNode x l r) = Just (x, l `merge` r)
```

... and the previous two queues can be adapted to work with the new `Queue`...

```
class Trivial a
instance Trivial a

instance Queue Trivial QueueA where
    {- as before -}
instance Queue Trivial LIFO where
    {- as before –}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be instance "Queue QueueA where"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd want something like

```
class Queue q where
    type Item q
    empty :: q
    (|>) :: q -> Item q -> q
    null :: q -> Bool
    head :: q -> Item q
    tail :: q -> q
    toList :: q -> [Item q]
```

With the instance

```
instance Queue (QueueA a) where
    type Item (QueueA a) = a

    empty = QA [] []

    (QA a b) |> e = norm $ QA a (e : b)

    ...
```

Note that this requires the `TypeFamilies` extension.

The reason for your error is because you're conflating the queue itself with the values inside the queue.  For example, you have

```
instance Queue (QueueA b) where  -- changed (QueueA a) to (QueueA b) for clarity
    head :: QueueA b -> QueueA b
    head ... = ...
```

Since `a ~ QueueA b` in your instance.  However, you're returning `b` with `Prelude.head`, hence the error.  You could also go with

```
class Queue q item where
    empty :: q item
    (|>) :: q item -> item -> q item
    null :: q item -> Bool
    head :: q item -> item
    tail :: q item -> q item
    toList :: q item -> [item]
```

With `MultiParamTypeClasses` and co (GHC will tell you which extensions to enable), but I've found that this approach is usually less flexible in practice when working with generic containers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how woud i use the TypeFamilies extension?

Comment: @user3742929 You would put `{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}` at the top of your file, same as any extension.

Comment: The class method `empty'
    mentions none of the type or kind variables of the class `Queue a'
    When checking the class method: empty :: forall q. q
    In the class declaration for `Queue'

Comment: @user3742929 Odd, the code I posted compiled for me under GHC 8.0.1.  That error message makes me think that you didn't copy my code correctly, though, since it says the type signature of `empty` is `:: q` but your typeclass is `class Queue a`.  Make sure your type variables are all the same.

Comment: Hmmm, checked again. Doesn't compile.

Comment: @user3742929 Sorry, that was my bad.  I re-read my post and noticed that I put the implementation for `null` as `empty`.  Check my edit and try again, because now I'm not being silly.

Comment: The standard (non-type-family) solutions would be `class Queue q item | q -> item where empty :: q; (|>) :: q -> item -> q` or the less flexible (but extension-free) `class Queue q where empty :: q item; (|>) :: q item -> item -> q item`. By comparison, your version has the flexibility and extension requirements of the fundep version but not its good type inference properties.

Comment: @bheklilr @DanielWagner Why use any extensions? What's wrong with `class Queue q where push :: a -> q a -> q a {- etc -}`?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson That is the less flexible but extension-free alternative I proposed in my comment. I say "less flexible" for the usual reasons: you cannot have a `Queue` instance that only works for `Ord`erable items, for example, and you cannot have a `Queue` instance that puts its item type somewhere other than its last argument (e.g. if you need to shuffle it earlier to be able to instantiate another class, or if your type is monomorphic, or similar).

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, apologies, I misread your comment. I've written up an answer elaborating on that idea